# LazyLoading not working in my entity using .net

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading, .net-6.0

Lazy loading is not working on my entity.

Here is my class:

```
public class Pergunta
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }        
    public int CategoriaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the class `Categoria`:

```
public class Categoria
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

But when I call this endpoint:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    List<Pergunta> teste = await _context.Pergunta.ToListAsync();
    return _context.Pergunta != null ?
                      View(await _context.Pergunta.ToListAsync()) :
                      Problem("Entity set 'SistemaJustificativasContext.Pergunta'  is null.");
}
```

The var `teste` says that `Categoria` is null:

[image]

Why is the lazy loading not working? Did I forget something?

Comment: You didn't enable lazyLoading. You need to do next `_context.Pergunta.Include(t => t.Categoria).do_what_you_want`

Comment: Lazy loading is not enabled by default. You need to turn it on. So if you still want to use lazy loading, then look into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy

Comment: But, if i have to use Include, it wouldn't be a EagerLoad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

> ```
> protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
> => optionsBuilder
>     .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
>     .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString);
> ```

see more details out there https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy as @scotty13 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `.Include` method (
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?view=efcore-7.0)

something like `_context.Pergunta.Include(x => x.Categoria)`